# What is the name for gold plated docking station contacts?

Tags: connector, identification, surface-mount

I design a device that must connect to the docking station which has spring loaded pins. I'm looking for gold plated contact for the device side (sample shown on the picture), so these contact pads would be exposed through the plastic case.

Any idea what name I should be searching for these kind of contacts under from suppliers?  I've been searching for multiple hours for "gold plated contact blocks", but haven't found yet.
[image]

Comment: try pcb spring contacts

Comment: It's easy to find the spring contacts and pogo pins, but how would you name this gold-plated block on the picture? This one goes against the spring contacts that I already have in place.

Comment: Try looking at the datasheet for the spring contacts, they should list a mating part.

Comment: You can just use gold plated PCB tracks. This is quite common in OEM products (just look at USB connectors). In this case it looks like they needed some extra height so added a proprietary spacer part.

Comment: Yeah. Gold plated PCB track is the way I go if can't find the suitable component. I would like those blocks (shown on the photo), because then they would fit better into my plastic case. With PCB track I can't level the contact surface with the case surface.

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: test point

More details:
Digikey have a dedicated [test point section](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/test-and-measurement/test-points/2294346) on their website. 
This covers all kinds of test points ranging from SMD to THT and tiny to XL.

One of my boards is using gold plated test points similar to these on your picture:
[HK-3-G-T from Manufacturer Mac8](http://www.mac8usa.com/test-point-hk3.php) (my BOM said Asianmicro though, this might be their previos name. Just speculation)